# Css font override

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm trying to override an in-line font style by CSS sheet but it doesn't work.
This is my rule on CSS:

```
art-blockcontent *{
    font-family:Verdana,Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif!important;
}
```

but the in-line styles continue to prevail on it.

This is the website: http://debatoversigt.dk/ and the css might style the left menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`art-blockcontent` is not a valid selector.

Judging by your markup, you need to make this element a class:

```
.art-blockcontent {
font-family:Verdana,Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif!important;
}
```